# Original references for Karp-Lipton theorem improvement by Sipser

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, circuit-complexity

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Lipton_theorem) about the Karp-Lipton theorem ($NP\subseteq P/poly$ implies $\Sigma_2=\Pi_2$), says the following:

> The Karp–Lipton theorem is named after Richard M. Karp and Richard J.
> Lipton, who first proved it in 1980. (Their original proof collapsed
> PH to $\Sigma_3$, but Michael Sipser improved it to $\Sigma_2$)

However, there's no reference to where Sipser proved this improvement.

Where can I find Sipser's improved proof of Karp-Lipton theorem?

**Edit**: to be clear, I'm looking for the original reference, not other resources explaining the result

Comment: I recommend you to watch [lecture 8 of 15-855 by Prof. Ryan O'Donnell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v02KnpmS0EY&list=PLm3J0oaFux3b8Gg1DdaJOzYNsaXYLAOKH&index=8), or the lecture notes at [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/complexity17/odonnell-graduate-complexity-notes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for the original reference, not other resources explaining it. I've clarified it in the question

Comment: In their original paper [\[STOC'80\] Some connections between nonuniform and uniform complexity classes](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/800141.804678), they mentioned "an improvement by Michael Sipser of an early result of ours", but no related reference is found. I guess maybe the original improvement is not published in a place that is easy to found.